# Make "physics" a tag synonym to "philosophy-of-physics"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think that [physics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) should be a synonym to [philosophy-of-physics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-physics), similarly to how the tags [mathematics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) and [science](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) have been treated (they are now synonyms). This would be most consistent with regard to the other tags. Questions here should arguably not be about "physics".

I don't have the reputation to suggest the tag synonym myself, which is why I'm posting this question. It would probably be best if a moderator created the synonym, since the procedure to vote on tags is pretty hopeless to use for smaller beta sites.

[psychology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) is another similar case, but there we lack the tag [philosophy-of-psychology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-psychology). So in general, a more consistent system for how to use scientific fields in tags would probably be a good idea. Another option would be to remove all the "philosophy-of-xxx" tags, and only keep subject-specific tags ("xxx", "yyy").

Comment: I guess you can simply flag one of the questions if you don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Keelan Yes, but the mods should see it here as well (I hope), and I thought that the more general question about tag naming should be open to discussion.

Comment: I've seen it. I'm just still thinking about it. I'm not a phil. science specialist, but I'd have to look through to see if the questions tagged "physics" have anything to do with "philosophy of physics" or if it is a good indicator that the people asking questions under "physics" are really just lost